# Remove all occurrences of a an ID from a multilevel array

Tags: mongodb

I have a structure as follows:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("609d931fe4cc0b0027485853"),
  blocks: [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("609d931fe4cc0b0027485855"),
      chunks: [
        ObjectId("609d543be4cc0b002748584c"), 
        ObjectId("609d54afe4cc0b002748584e")
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("609d931fe4cc0b0027485854"),
      chunks: [
        ObjectId("609d543be4cc0b002748584c"), 
        ObjectId("609d54afe4cc0b002748584e")
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("609d5401e4cc0b0027485849"),
  blocks: [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("609d71cde4cc0b002748584f"),
      chunks: [
        ObjectId("609d543be4cc0b002748584c"), 
        ObjectId("609d54afe4cc0b002748584e")
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("60999d7ee4cc0b002748583f"),
      chunks: [
        ObjectId("609d543be4cc0b002748584c"), 
        ObjectId("609d54afe4cc0b002748584e")
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

I want to delete all chunks with a certain id from all blocks and for all documents.
My query is the following:

```
  Document.update(
      { 'blocks.chunks': chunk._id },
      { $pull: {'blocks.$.chunks': chunk._id} },
      { multi: true }
    )
```

The problem I have is that when I run this command for chunk id `609d543be4cc0b002748584c`, the chunk is deleted from all documents but only for the first element in the `blocks` array.

Is there a way to remove all chunks from all blocks from all documents for a given chunk id?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: this `'schedule.$.chunks'` field `schedule` i can not see in your documents.

Comment: try adding empty array brackets with $ `{'blocks.$[].chunks': chunk._id}`.

Comment: @turivishal sorry, that was a typo. I edited the question.
I also tried the `$[]` notation in both the query and the update but then nothing gets deleted.

Comment: @FedericoFreire You need to remove all chunks id form all document.So you dont need filter. `{}, { $pull: {'blocks.$[].chunks': chunk._id} }, { multi: true }` . Hope this would work

Comment: Thanks, @varman and @turivishal. The `$[]` notation was in fact the solution.

It wasn't working for me because I was still using mongoose 4.x. Updating the library fixed the issue.